# Multiple Foreign keys between two tables

Tags: sql, database

I have a table called Tbl_Event that stores basic information for upcoming events.

```
Tbl_Event

EventID  Description  Location
```

I have another table called staff that stores staff information

```
  Tbl_Staff

 StaffID  Name
```

Now each event can have multiple staff members, to achieve this I have created a new table

```
   tbl_Event_Staff

   RecordID  StaffID   EventID
```

StaffID and EventID have a COMBINED unique constraint on them.
There is an added condition, where one of the staff member needs to be the supervisor of the event. What is the best possible solution to achieve this, Should I add an extra column in tbl_event - SupervisorID

```
Tbl_Event

EventID  Description  Location  SupervisorID
```

and link it to tbl_Event_Staff on StaffID( in this case there will be to foreign keys between these two tables - EventID and StaffID)

or 
* I dont think this is the best solution to to redundant data.

Should I add an extra column to tbl_Event_Staff - isSupervisor(bool) and for each row have a boolean variable that denotes if the staff for that EVENT is supervisor or not.

```
 tbl_Event_Staff

   RecordID  StaffID   EventID   IsSupervisor
      1        10        3         true
      2        20        3         false
      3        30        3         false
```

or

Is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the second approach, and, however possible, would place a constraint on this table such that only *one* row for each `EventID` can be a supervisor.

The details of how to do this vary between databases - in some systems, it may have to be enforced with a trigger. In [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188783.aspx), it could be done using a filtered index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON EventStaff (EventID) WHERE IsSupervisor = 1
```

---

I'd also recommend doing away with the `tbl_` prefixes - there's no sane reason to use prefixes to distinguish object types in SQL - the syntax of the language means that you can tell the type of an object purely by its position in the query - except in one situation.

The situation I refer to is that views and tables may appear in the same positions in queries and be indistinguishable. However, this is a *good* thing - in general, you shouldn't care whether the object you're dealing with is a table or a view - the database developer should be free to create a different table structure and re-create the older structure using views in the place of the original tables - and existing queries shouldn't be affected.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Is this the best approach to solve this issue? I will have a lot of redundant data and it will be a lot harder to update the database. Although, come to think of it whenever the user sets a staff as supervisor I can loop through all the staffID's for that event and set the IsSupervisor flag to false but then this table wont be normalized properly. guess that's the price I'll have to npay.

Comment: @Abhi.Net - well, you have two answers so far, and we disagree. Take this as a sign that there isn't a "best approach". Only you know what queries and operation you'll need to support from these data structures. And, as I indicate in my aside, you can (from either design) construct views that mimic the other design - so if you decide later that the other structure is more appropriate, you can rebuild it and then only need to re-write those queries that benefit from the re-design.

Comment: thats what I think, The only reason I am stressing for to get the best solution is that this is part of an ER diagram assignment where I need to create a database structure and normalize it. Everything is done except this part and I am not sure which approach to follow but I'll probably chose the second one and then leave a comment explaining my choice.

Comment: @Abhi.Net - also, as to your statements "I can loop through...", no, that's the wrong aproach. You'd write a single query that performs all of the updates in one go. E.g. if StaffID 10 is the new supervisor for event 3, you'd write `UPDATE EventStaff SET IsSupervisor = CASE WHEN StaffID=10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END WHERE EventID=3`

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is better, because it automatically guards you from creating events with zero supervisors and/or events with multiple supervisors: when an event's `supervisor_id` column is non-nullable, your RDBMS ensures that there is precisely one supervisor for each event.

If you need to get your results in the form of a table with a `true/false` indicator marking the supervisor, you can always get that result by joining to `Tbl_Event`, and comparing `Tbl_Event.supervisor` to `tbl_Event_Staff.StaffID`.

Comment: But is it a good idea to have foreign key relation between to columns and none of them are primary keys? In tbl_event and tbl_event_staff both staffid and supervisorID are non-key attributes.

Comment: @Abhi.Net I wouldn't link it to `tbl_Event_Staff`, I'd link it directly to `Tbl_Staff`, where `StaffID` is the primary key.

Comment: I actually did think about it but in that case I can have a staffId in my tbl_event while there is no record in tbl_staff_event. Which means a staff is working as a supervisor in the event yet has no record in tbl_staff_event.